# React native TouchableHighlight not working

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a login page with this code:

```
<View style={styles.formContainer}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.authentication}>
        <Icon.Button name="facebook" style={styles.loginIconButton}>
            <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Login with Facebook</Text>
        </Icon.Button>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

when running this it gives '**Touchable child must be native or forward setNativeProps to a native component**', so I wrapped the Icon in a View, as suggested by other posts:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.authentication.bind(this)}>
    <View>
        <Icon.Button name="facebook" style={styles.loginIconButton}>
            <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Login with Facebook</Text>
        </Icon.Button>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

now the on press event is not triggered any more. But if I remove the `Icon.Button` tag and leave just Text it works fine. How can I fix this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try getting rid of the outer `TouchableHighlight` and just add the `onPress` event to `Icon.Button`?

If you look into the code for `Icon.Button` here (I'm guessing that you're using `react-native-vector-icons`), you can actually see that it creates a `TouchableHighlight` element as an inherent part of the element: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/lib/icon-button.js

Try moving `onPress` to `Icon.Button`, remove the extraneous wrapping views, and let us know how it works!

Comment: yep, it works like a charm - should have looked into the sources first :)